# Learning MPLAB XC

Tags: pic, mplab

I am trying to learn mplab xc8. I am familiar with C and C++. I have written some code using these languages. But while I am trying to learn mplab, I couldn't find any good source or book. For example I know what TRIS means but I don't know how to write it to program (btw I know how).

Neither datasheet nor mplab help section worked for me. I mean for example while I am learning C language there are a lot of books which explain code and how to use it.

Where should I start to study?

Comment: Try looking around [Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/). For instance, [Programming PIC Microcontrollers](http://www.instructables.com/id/Programming-PIC-Microcontrollers/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some resources about Microchip on their [developer's website](http://microchipdeveloper.com). You will find some example about 8,16,32 bits microcontrollers and more.

You can also take a look on [some code examples](https://www.microchip.com/doclisting/TechDoc.aspx?type=CodeExamples).

Did you ever write some code for microcontrollers? If not, buy a development board, you will have plenty of code examples for a specific dev board.

Comment: Thank you. Then you mean I can learn these concepts with examples.

Answer (score 0):

(Note that, when I last checked, MPLAB X IDE is supplied separately from the compilers XC8, XC16, and XC32.)

XC8 compiles C89 a.k.a. C90 with a few extensions, all documented in the User Guide. (Soon it will compile C99 and C11 when asked, but that has not yet been released.)

When you `#include <xc.h>`, that pulls in declarations for the various Special Function Registers on the chip you select at compile-time. These SFRs are specified as integers and bitfields of appropriate sizes. You simply read from them and write to them just like you would any other variable.